# how to send output of ssh to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a command that wants to connect remote server with ssh.My command is

```
"ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $REMOTE_HOST_IP > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

When this works the true message comes "Permission denied".It is the true message but i dont want to see message on console so i redirected it to /dev/null.But is still comes.What is the problem

Edit:
I tried as you say and taking 2&1 before /dev/null but still it does not work.But it is strange that it works on my friends computer

SOLVED:Problem is that I assigned the command to a variable and the run it as $command.But when it is set between "" redirection does not work

Answer (score 3):

Look at `-n` option

> ```
> -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from
>          stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.  A
>          common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote
>          machine.  For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will
>          start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will
>          be automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh
>          program will be put in the background.  (This does not work if
>          ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f
>          option.)
> ```

Or even on `-N`

> ```
>  -N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for‐
>          warding ports (protocol version 2 only).
> ```

Comment: Note that the question is about redirecting standard and AFAIK your answer is about redirecting standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $REMOTE_HOST_IP &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (moving the `2>&1` redirecting stderr before sending it to /dev/null):

```
 "ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $REMOTE_HOST_IP 2>&1 > /dev/null"
```

Note that you are redirecting stderr to stdout with your `2>&1`. If you just want to redirect stderr to /dev/null then simply use `2> /dev/null`.

Good information about [IO Redirection here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Comment: Inverting `2>&1` and `>/dev/null` doesn't solve the problem. It just make "error" redirected to stdout while "normal" output is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no $REMOTE_HOST_IP 2> /dev/null`